# workflow status on a third-party website

Tags: workflow, alfresco, status, workflow-activity

In Alfresco community launched workflow, for example Approval document.
I want to show workflows details on personal website(the status of the process, the start date, term)
How can I implement it? (Repository JavaScript API,RESTful API or what else?)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you explain what you mean? Also, please note: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to build a java backed webscript. This means you create a spring bean which extends from webscript.
(more info in https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Java-Backed_Implementations )

In this spring bean you should inject the workflowservice.

```
<bean id="webscript.com.mycompany.workflowinformation.get" class="com.mycompany.GetWorkflowinformation"  parent="webscript">
    <property name="workflowService">
        <ref bean="WorkflowService" />
    </property> 
</bean
```

You can then use this WorkflowService in your java class to query information about the state and the tasks of your workflow. Then return this information using your webscript response writer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use webscript,create webscript for getting details of workflow.In webscript you can filter data also.Other option is to use CMIS API of alfresco.

In case of webscript ,you will get more idea on below link.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts

I just get realized,that there is already one webscript which returns workflow details.If you dont need extra information other than this you can use this.You can also add some extra fields in this.For more details of this webscript.Browse webscripts by hitting http://localhost:8080/alfresco/serviceindex url.

[http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/task-instances?authority=admin&properties=bpm_priority,bpm_status,bpm_dueDate,bpm_description&exclude=wcmwf:*&skipCount=0&maxItems=50](http://50.56.224.213:8080/proxy/alfresco/api/task-instances?authority=admin&properties=bpm_priority,bpm_status,bpm_dueDate,bpm_description&exclude=wcmwf:*&skipCount=0&maxItems=50)

Comment: I am find this script in scripts home, its name "Gets workflow task instance"?

Comment: no,its not that one,you will find it only in source code.

Comment: last your link return {
   "data": 
   [
   ]

  ,
    "paging": 
    {
      "maxItems": 50,
      "skipCount": 0,
      "totalItems": 0,
      "totalItemsRangeEnd": null,
      "confidence": "exact"
    }
}

Comment: It is returning that because ,there is no task in mytask for admin user.

Comment: try with removing authority parameter.

Comment: without authority parameter the same

Comment: that what i said in answer,manipulate with parameters and see webscript.you will get more on that.